# getting error in Spring Batch, Job builder and step builder. get function not working with it

Tags: spring-batch

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return   this.stepBuilder.get("step1")
```

I'm getting this error:

> The method get(String) is undefined for the type StepBuilder please
> assist

Solution for the mentioned, i'm getting error in spring batch.

Comment: Which version of Spring Batch do you use? Have you checked how to configure a step here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringAStep?  Please share more details about your code to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine
am using spring 5.0

Comment: @Bean
 public Job importUserJob() {
   return  this.jobBuilder.get("USER-IMPORT-JOB")
     .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
     .flow(step1())
     .end()
     .build();
  }
   
  
  public Step step1() {
      return   stepBuilder.get("step1")
              .<User, User> chunk(1)
              .reader(reader())
              .processor(processor())
              .writer(writer())
              .build();
  }

Comment: Please do not add code in comments, it is not readable. You can edit the question and add code there: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Issue is resolved by referring https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringAStep.
Thanks Ben